# Casting to a decimal in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The max value in my table for `measure_rate` is `572`. The below query returns that value.

```
SELECT cast(max(measure_rate) as decimal) 
FROM [SurgicalMeasures]
WHERE measure_rate != 'N/a'
      and zip_code = 21236
```

But when I change the above query to the query below, it gives me `95` as the max number.

```
SELECT cast(max(measure_rate) as decimal) 
FROM [SurgicalMeasures]
WHERE measure_rate != 'N/a'
```

My question is if I know `572` is the max `measure_rate` why are these queries returning different results?

The data type of the `measure_rate` column is a `varchar(50)`

Comment: what is the datatype of measure_rate column? it seems varchar to me, am i right? 1st correct the data type in your column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting to decimal first, then take the max of that casted value:

```
select max(cast(measure_rate as decimal(10,2))) as max_rate
from [SurgicalMeasures]
where measure_rate != 'N/a';
```

The potential problem with your current approach is that if `measure_rate` be text, then it may not sort properly as a number.  That is, the `MAX()` function may return an incorrect value.

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to update all the N/A to null like below

```
update SurgicalMeasures
set measure_rate=null
where  measure_rate != 'N/a'
```

Then alter the column from varchar to decimal

```
ALTER TABLE SurgicalMeasures 
ALTER COLUMN measure_rate decimal(10,4);
```

then execute your query

```
SELECT max(measure_rate) as mr
FROM [SurgicalMeasures]
```

Comment: `MODIFY` in SQL Server??